# CentOS 6.5 Installation Failure

Tags: centos, system-installation

I am trying to install CentOS 6.5 but it gets stuck here:
[image: CentOS 6.5 Installation Failure]

What could be the problem?

Comment: You may try downloading a new iso and create a bootable device from that new iso. Most of the time problems regarding installation are related to corrupt iso/bootable device,

Comment: The problem was solved after changing the boot device and adding acpi=off in the boot parameters.